# FactoryGirl creation mysteriously fails on automated CI server (CircleCI) but not when run manually

Tags: rspec, factory-bot, circleci

I have a `Community` model and an associated `:community` factory to create it in tests.

Several tests depend on a community existing, and many tests use it as a memo-ized helper with `let`

```
let(:community) { create(:community) }
```

All of these tests are failing when running on CircleCI, which my team uses for CI. One example -

```
342) Communities Index Page user can navigate to their existing community
   Failure/Error: let(:community) { create(:community) }
   ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
     Failed to save the record
   # ./spec/factories/communities.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/features/communities/communities_all_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/features/communities/communities_all_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/support/analytics.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

They pass locally without issue. Even more mysteriously, if I ssh into the CircleCI build box and run that exact same spec manually - it passes!

```
$ bundle exec rspec ./spec/features/communities/communities_all_spec.rb:12
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/features/communities/communities_all_spec.rb"=>[12]}}

Randomized with seed 36500
.

Finished in 1.85 seconds (files took 9.64 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 36500
```

I'm not even sure where to begin debugging what could be happening.

Comment: Which version of Rails?

Comment: How does your factory look like? What validations do you have in your model? Do you have unique indexes or not null constraints on your database table?